# What is the meaning of " leave" in the following news head line

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "leave" in the following news headline

"virus leaves 30000 dead in europe alone"

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. "to be taken" is an euphamism for dying, the opposite would be "to be left" (ie. "to remain alive").

Comment: Cambridge does not cover this usage, but [MW's definition at 1B](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of the word leave over here means:

> The virus has left behind 30,000 people dead in Europe alone.

Leave means [leaving behind as a result of a circumstance or situation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave) (A2). For e.g. the prisoner was left to die in a dark cell for his crimes.

Comment: Thanks @Bitterdreggs. corrected the sentence